# DIY method for regenerating activated carbon in air filters

Tags: aromatic-compounds, hydrocarbons, surface-chemistry, adsorption, filtering

I am interested in regenerating activated carbon used in general house-hold air filters. I am looking for a sufficiently efficient and easy method to do this in home setting. A little tinkering in a workshop is possible, but sophisticated laboratory or industrial protocols are out of reach.

I think the most probable mechanism would be the desorption of attached non-polar molecules by heat, already discussed [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/606/activated-carbon-desorption-in-sunlight/610#610). What are the required temperatures to desorb typical gases in houses that attach into the activated carbon, and what heating times are required? If necessary, to avoid oxygen attacking (burning) the activated carbon in high temperatures, I think (super)heated water vapor would be the easiest inert gas to obtain. But is it needed and suitable? And whatever method is used, the activated carbon should not liberate polluting carbon particles itself more than it typically does, and even less carcinogens. I know that activated carbon is a little bit dusty, but the method should not cause excess amount of particles.